# Bibliography in wrong format when in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, amsrefs

I am using the report class and using `\usepackage{amsrefs}` as my citation style.  When creating the table of contents, in order to get LaTeX to treat the bibliography as a section, I used the command `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}`.  However, this only causes the table of contents to only have "Bibliography" listed as opposed to "VII Bibliography" listed.

Is there a way that I can have the table of contents show "VII Bibliography" for my citations?

Any help would be much appreciated

Edit: Forgot to put in troublesome code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{page}
\newpage
\section{Summary}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
text text text

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{amsrefs}
\bibliography{wood}

\section{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you give us a mwe?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you use? Having an MWE (minimum working example -- starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}) that generates the problem behavior you're trying to solve would be most helpful.

Comment: Why are you using `report` if you have no chapters?

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{VII}Bibliography}` for a quick hack.

Answer (score 3):

The `report` class has chapters, so it's rather strange you don't use them.

There's no `\bibliographystyle{amsrefs}` to use with `amsrefs`, just `\bibliography` is sufficient. In the example I have used `filecontents*` and `\jobname` as the `.bib` file name just to make it self-contained.

Since `amsrefs` uses either `\bibchapter` or `\bibsection` for the bibliography title, a simple way to number the bibliography is to remove the `*` that follows `\chapter` or `\section` in the definition of those commands.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abc,
 author={A. U. Thor and W. Riter},
 title={A title},
 journal={The Journal},
 year={2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\bibchapter}{*}{}{}{}
%%% use the following for the article class
%\xpatchcmd{\bibsection}{*}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Summary}
\chapter{Introduction}
text text text\cite{abc}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure if I get you right. You don't have any chapters but are using the `report` class. But well, I don't have a roman numbering as you asked for with "VII Bibliography" but at least, it will show a numbered section "Bibliography" in your TOC. Please clarify your question, if this is not what you want:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{page}
\newpage
\section{Summary}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
text text text

\addtocounter{section}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{amsrefs}
\bibliography{wood}

\section{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]